# Unable to reinstall Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2019

I tried to reinstall my Visual studio 2019 today and after I uninstall it I could not install it again.
Visual studio installer is starting, showing dialog to chose components and when I select what I need I click Install button and... Installer window disappears and there are 2 instances of installer in Task Manager one of which is loading CPU from 12 to 17 per cent and another one just sitting there never showing any signs of life. No errors or any signs of malfunctioning shown by Installer or could be found in a logs. Event Viewer also contains nothing.

Things I tried:

1. Deleting files from AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio
2. Rebooting
3. Redownloading Installer
4. Waited on  running instance of Installer for quite some time, but without much of the success

Nothing works. I am out of ideas what possibly could be wrong. Never faced such a problem before. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

**1)** delete any folders like`C:\Users\perryq\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxxx`

and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\xxx`

**Then**,

run **vs_installer** as **Administrator** and try again.

**Besides**, if it still does not work, I suggest you could try to do a clean uninstallation of VS on your PC.

**a)** run `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\InstallCleanup.exe`, and it will uninstall all VS2017 and VS2019's version, caches, the registration information on your PC. If your PC does not have any other version or if you do not mind it, you can just execute it.

**And** when you finish it, you can run the latest `vs_installer` as **Administrator** to reinstall it again to test it.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but after I follow steps you've provided I had same result: installer is starting , I am getting to the page where I selecting components to install and after clicking "Install" button Installer windows disappears without any messages or indication of distress. I am truly baffled.

Comment: Maybe there are other third party startup programs that affect this. So please turn off any antivirus software, third party startup programs. Then, open the installer to test again. Also, when you shut down the vs installer process under Task Manager, did the installer start when you click again? Or you could use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to monitor the status.